# Clojure , pigpen, unable to access function parameter

Tags: clojure, apache-pig

I have problem accesing function parameter in a pig/map function.
Here is an exemple

```
 (defn date-interval
  ([start end] (date-interval start end []))
  ([start end interval]
   (if (co/after? start end)
     interval
     (recur (co/plus start (co/days 1)) end (concat interval [start])))))

(defn open-date [start end close-date]
  (->> close-date
   (pig/map (fn [x]
              {:toto (:toto x)
               :open-date (remove (:close-date x) (date-interval start end))}))))
```

I am trying to execute

```
(open-date start end close-date)
```

Were close date is the result of a pig job  and i get

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: start in this context
```

I do not understant why I can't acess to that specific value.

Thanks for your help

**EDIT**

I solve my problem by changing start and end format. From org.joda.time.DateTime to String.

Comment: Is the `start` defined in scope where you call `open-date` function? It's possible that invocation of function fails, not the function itself.

Comment: Yes the start is defined